# mongodb change streams: How do you TypeScript "change" event?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, changestream

I upgraded from `mongoose` v5 to v6 and now the following code no longer works.  `ChangeEvent<ListingDocument>` is no longer the correct type for the change parameter.

Here is the code that worked on mongoose v5:

```
export default function watchListing() {
    Listing.watch([], {fullDocument: "updateLookup"}).on("change", change => {
        watchUpdatePrices(change);
    });
}

function watchUpdatePrices(change: ChangeEvent<ListingDocument>) {
    ...
});
```

Now I get the follow error:

```
Argument of type 'ChangeStreamDocument<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ChangeEvent<ListingDocument>'.
  Type 'ChangeStreamDropDocument' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEvent<ListingDocument>'.
    Type 'ChangeStreamDropDocument' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEventOther<ListingDocument>'.
      Types of property '_id' are incompatible.
        Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'ResumeToken'.ts(2345)
```

How have you Typed change streams?

Answer (score 1):

Use **ChangeStreamDocument** from mongodb(v6).

```
import { ChangeStreamDocument } from 'mongodb';
export default function watchListing() {
Listing.watch([], {fullDocument: "updateLookup"}.on("change", change:ChangeStreamDocument<ListingDocument> => {
    watchUpdatePrices(change);
});
}
function watchUpdatePrices(change: ChangeStreamDocument<ListingDocument>) {
        ...
    // Check  ListingDocument.operationType to get respective type for update,create,del etc
    if(data.operationType==="update"){
      //then ... 
    }
});
```

Comment: May I ask what is `ListingDocument` in here?